# Game map for DirectX

Tags: c++, directx-9

I am making a game in DirectX 9/C++. I do not have a lot of knowledge about directX. I want to make a map for my game similar to GTA 1. I want to know is there a way to make whole map in some other software and then import and render that map in my directX application.

If, not what are alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX is not a game engine. DirectX is a programming API. Things like maps, game logic, and so on are completely beyond what DirectX does. It's your burden, as a programmer to implement these things.

Honestly, if you have to ask this question, you should not use DirectX directly, if you want results fast. Instead use an existing, available game engine and implement your game using that. In the past years a number of high quality engines have become available for little money or even free. To name a few:

- Unity
- Unreal Engine or SDK
- CryEngine
- Source SDK

There are also a few open source worth looking at:

- IrrLicht
- Ogre
- CrystalSpace

You may also want to look at open source games, which engine you can repurpose. Specifically I'm thinking about *Cube2 / Sauerbraten* and it's successor *Tesseract* here.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a small world creater to suit my needs. Using it I placed different objects and import that map for later use.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend to use an Engine like Unreal Engine 4. You can get it for little money and it does a lot for you. You can spend a lot of time in designing your game, so you dont need to spend that much time which directx and stuff.